# Remove space from top of text in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

There is a UILabel in UITableView cell. If label have long text then it adds some space on top from text in label. After scrolling this space is automatically remove. I want to remove this space initially. What should i do. I have adjusting height of label using this code:

```
- (void) adjustHeightOfLbl : (UILabel *) lbl : (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

    NSAttributedString *attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:(lbl.text?:@"")
                                    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: lbl.font}];
    CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){lbl.frame.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               context:nil];
    CGSize size = rect.size;

    CGRect newFrame = lbl.frame;
    newFrame.size.height = size.height;

    lbl.frame = newFrame;

}
```

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738264/label-doesnt-start-from-top-left

Comment: Can U give scrrenshot for what do u want to achieve?